# add hours to date not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to add hours to date using this function:

```js
function addHoursToDate(date, hours) {
    return new Date(new Date(date).setHours(date.getHours() + hours));
}

const now = new Date();

console.log('now', now);

console.log('then', addHoursToDate(now, 1));
```

The weird issue is here on SO we get the correct result but if you use the same code on node.js both logs are the same.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I don't get the same result when I run the code above. Check again, please?

Comment: Yeah , I noticed this here, And it cofuses me more... please read the updated question again

Comment: I've checked with Node.js on my machine - two different times are logged. How are you running this code?

Comment: Always set a timezone on your datetimes, so that you at least know which timezone's quirks you need to look up when "time arithmetic" doesn't do what you expected it to do.

Comment: Please have a look at the image ..

Comment: `Always set a timezone on your datetimes` I don't know how to do this..

Comment: Do not put images of text in your post: put the text itself in, instead. As for setting a timezone, JS dates use standard unix timestamp notation including the `+...` timezone indicator suffix (easy enough to find more information on, it's pretty well-documented). If you don't, the times you get will be whatever timezone your computer's set to (but print as UTC). Having said that: I can't reproduce this behaviour, both the browser and node do exactly the same thing, so unless you can add more details that let others reproduce _your_ setup this is likely to get closed as "not reproducible".

Comment: `return new Date(Number(date)+36e5);` should return an extra hour

Comment: What is your Node version (`node --version`)? What's your time zone (`echo "$TZ"` and in Node: `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`)? Which OS and OS version are you running? Where are you running this code in (is that just your OS' terminal in the window, or something like Cygwin?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without function

```
const now = new Date();

console.log('now', now);
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1)
console.log('then', now);
```

or with function

```
function addHoursToDate(date, hours) {
date.setHours(date.getHours() + hours)
    return date;
}
const now = new Date();
console.log('now', now);
console.log('then', addHoursToDate(now, 1));
```

Comment: Wait, What? Your Solution is working!!!

Comment: So how it's different in Node.js ??

Comment: now.getHours() should be date .getHours() in your function...

Comment: @SaraRee if you check back, maybe your original solution is working now as well. It's something about your environment, most likely - not the code itself.

Comment: I tried to make function simple for you. some time code behaves weird if not written well.